# iOS 7 backBarButtonItem hidden

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, ios7

I've an issue with back bar button. It stay hidden no matter that i do like `self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton`

Here is my code to add back button:

```
//
    - (void)viewDidLoad{

    [.....];

    UIBarButtonItem *back = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"UI_BTN_BACK", nil) style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
    back.tintColor = [Templates getColor:@"color"];
    [[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem:back];

    // Parent
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Button stay hidden BUT going back works if if touch on the place where it should be.
Of course it works on iOS6.
Another detail: back button seems to appear when i set UINavigationBar translucent to YES.

Thanks

Comment: Wow no i don't want it to be hidden! It is hidden at the moment and i don't know why. If i try `[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:NO];` it still hidden :(

Comment: What does `NSLog` output when you call `NSLocalizedString(@"UI_BTN_BACK", nil)`?

Comment: output is "Back", my title is OK ;)

Comment: Is the tint color the same as the background color of your nav bar? Try setting .layer.borderColor and .layer.borderWidth on the back button and see if the rect is wrong somehow.

Comment: Are you setting the `backButtonItem` in the correct view? 

For example, if you have a ListView and a DetailView, the `backButtonItem` that appears in the DetailView has to be set in ListView. Your code should work, but it will not do anything unless it's added to the ListView, (i.e. the higher level in the navigation hierarchy).

Comment: Setting the tint color does not work. Anyway, `backButtonItem` is in the correct view. As I say, the strange thing is that the button appears if **I set UINavigationBar translucent to YES**...

Comment: Ok new informations: it seems that the color of the back button is the same as the navigation bar (this is why i can see the back button when bar is set to transluscent). Anyway, i tried multiple way to change the button color but it's not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = nil;
```

OR

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];
```

Check out this.

Comment: Same answer as above : "no i don't want it to be hidden! It is hidden at the moment and i don't know why. If i try `[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:NO];` it still hidden :("

Answer (score 2):

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```