# My Custom UINavigationController won't show right button

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a "LoginViewController" which presents a new Controller which is a subclass of `UINavigationcontroller` when clicking a button:

```
MPNavigationViewController *controller = [[MPNavigationViewController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[MPQuestionFirstViewController alloc] init]];

[self presentViewController: controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

"MPNavigationViewController" subclass `UINavigationController` and uses "REMenu" to have a sliding-from-top menu ("[Link](https://github.com/romaonthego/REMenu)") and on `viewDidLoad` I try to add a right button to open it:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  UIBarButtonItem *toggleMenuButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Show" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(toggleMenu:)];
  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = toggleMenuButton;
  [self initMenu];
}
```

It doesn't show any button on the navigation bar. Why could it be?

If I try to add the button from one of the "viewControllers" that will handle sections on the menu. It shows the button, but it doesn't paint it at all.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23802507/1378447

Answer (score 0):

You are using subclass of UINavigationcontroller which is not actually view controller.
There is only one solution, You need to create your custom button and add it to UINavigationbar as a subview..

Answer (score -1):

Use this hope it will help.

```
UIBarButtonItem *doneButton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone  target:self action:@selector(goToDoneButtonAction)];

 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneButton;
```